# Alternative function for case match in haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am writing an API in Haskell which involves a DB query.
Function will be something like do a db query and then return the response back.

```hs
doAPICall :: Request -> (Monad m Response)
doAPICall req = do
    maybeValDB <- getValFromDB (req.tokenId) -- Returns maybe type
    -- My current logic was to do a case match of maybe
    case maybeValDB of
        Just val -> do
            --Some logic here using that val and return the response
            pure response
        Nothing -> pure response
```

I am currently getting a maybe type from the DB query function. Is there a simple way like a one liner code to avoid this case match and send the response back.

I thought of using `fromMaybe` but it should have same type for the default value. Here in this case if db returns Nothing I just want to exit the function with some response.

In general in many cases the response which I get will be of maybe type and I have to do case matches the code looks very ugly and have repetitive patterns. Can anyone tell me better alternative for this instead of having case matches everywhere.

Comment: What is `response`?

Comment: @DanielWagner something of this type

Response
      { status          :: Text,
        responseCode    :: Maybe Text,
        responseMessage :: Maybe Text,
        payload         :: Maybe ResponsePayload
      }

Comment: I mean, given the literal code you show here, you can just replace the whole `case` statement with `pure response`. So I'm assuming that this is just some placeholder code. But what I'm trying to tell you is that placeholder code isn't good enough to make an answer; there are different solutions for different things that set apart the two `response`s. We need more details to be able to help you.

Comment: I am doing another api call inside the just part and doing some update in the db and sending success response. I think the code I gave is enough to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps what you're looking for is [`maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe)?

```hs
doAPICall :: Request -> (Monad m Response)
doAPICall req = do
    maybeValDB <- getValFromDB (req.tokenId)
    flip (maybe $ pure response) maybeValDB $ \val -> do
      -- Some logic here using that val and return the response
      pure response
```